# How to get picture boxes to display a message box when touching

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
    private void GameScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Time = 1;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1;
        Time += 1;

    }

    private void Character_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameScreen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         int x = CharacterUser.Location.X;
         int y = CharacterUser.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 4;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 4;

        CharacterUser.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }

    public void Block_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    private void IsTouching(PictureBox CharacterUser, PictureBox Block)
    {
        if (CharacterUser.Location.X + CharacterUser.Width < Block.Location.X)
            MessageBox.Show("Continue? You survived for", +Time, "You failed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (Block.Location.X + Block.Width < CharacterUser.Location.X)
            MessageBox.Show("Continue? You survived for", +Time, "You failed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (CharacterUser.Location.Y + CharacterUser.Height < Block.Location.Y)
            MessageBox.Show("Continue? You survived for", +Time, "You failed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (Block.Location.Y + Block.Height < CharacterUser.Location.Y)
            MessageBox.Show("Continue? You survived for", +Time, "You failed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    }


    }
}
```

I'm not sure why when I move one of the picture boxes using the code in GameScreen_KeyDown so that it's touching the other picture box a message box does not appear and timer isn't recognised in the message text even though I defined it in timer1_Tick, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When/where do you call `IsTouching()`?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - `timer1.Interval = 1;` that is an unrealistic value. Resolution is around 20-30 ms, not 1! Also. Tick is the event. No use to start the Timer __there__!! All (or at least) the code there should move somewhere else.. Most likely you want to move there and then test..